# Android x86 > error: SysRq: Emergency remount R/0

Tags: boot, reboot, mount, android-x86

I have a **PC** with **Windows 10** and **Ubuntu 18.04**, but would like to add more **Android x86**(*lineageOS 14.1*). The **ISO** file works perfectly in **Live USB**. After installing with **USB** (by selecting "**Run LineageOS**"), the android launches without problems. But after the restart (added **lineageOS 14.1** via `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`), it does start with the following message:

```
Detecting Android-x86... found at /dev/sda7
[     3.697517] sysrq: SysRq: Emergency remount R/0
```

Then it reboots to the **GRUB2** menu.

How do I fix this, and boot **lineageOS 14.1**?

My **PC** with an **CPU** Intel Celeron 2.6 GHz 1 core, 1GB ram, and I am trying to start **lineageOS 14.1** on a 8GB partition (without SDcard).

My boot code is:

```
    recordfail=1
    if [ -n ${have_grubenv} ]; then save_env recordfail; fi
set quiet=1
insmod ext2
set root=(hd0,7)
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 033e8fc7-4cfe-9454-bc59-df7329ca862d
linux /cm-x86-14.1-r2/kernel root=UUID=033e8fc7-4cfe-9454-bc59-df7329ca862d ro quiet splash
initrd /cm-x86-14.1-r2/initrd.img
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **I solved this problem!**

### [This code](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-x86/fUCo8QaiqXU/4sUjdlsHBAAJ) for the **GRUB2** loader helped me.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](/help/how-to-answer).